# install libxcb 1.13 under deepin (debian)

Tags: python, linux, debian-based, xcb

Since libxcb 1.12 had problems with python3 I am now trying to install the new libxcb 1.13 packages, however apt-get claims that Version 1.12-1 is already the newest. How can I get install the newer 1.13 version?

Comment: "Since libxcb 1.12 had problems with python3" - could elaborate? XCB only uses python at built-time, so if you already have an installed version of libxcb, what problem remains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the first time I heard about deepin and sadly their web page does not offer something like http://packages.debian.org.

Since you mention that it is based on Debian: Can one install packages from Debian in deepin (without messing everything up)? If so, you could download the `.deb` file from debian and install with `dpkg -i`.

Alternatively, you could try getting the source for debian's libxcb package from https://salsa.debian.org/xorg-team/lib/libxcb and build your own package via `dpkg-buildpackage`.

Comment: That actually worked! I didn't know that the Debian Website offers downloads of .deb packages.